# mssql unable to execute multiple ID's in one short

Tags: php, sql

> Delete from tblStats where indexID in (1,2,3,5,7,8,9,11...........250900)

mssql_query function unable to delete all these ID's as well no error thrown also affected rows says -1. this same query successfully deleted in sql server 2008 tool.

is there any limitation exist in the mssql_query for DELETE Query.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question, but one potential issue is the size of you `IN` statement.

You would be better off builidng a temp table and populating it with the list of values and then using that temp temp in a `JOIN`.